# Adicionar primeiro item no JComboBox

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

Estou preechendo meu JComboBox assim:

```
 private void preencherCombo(  ){        
        jComboEstado.removeAllItems();        
        List<Estado> lista = ec.listaObj("");        
       jComboEstado.addItem("Selecione um estado");        
        for( Estado e: lista ){
            jComboEstado.addItem(e);
        }
    }
```

Estou tentando ler a opção selecionada do combobox assim:

```
Estado e = (Estado) jComboEstado.getSelectedItem();
```

Meu JComboBox está declarado assim:

```
 private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboEstado;
```

Gostaria de adicionar o primeiro Item:

```
jComboEstado.addItem("Selecione um estado");
```

Mas está dando esse problema

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to br.com.brito.pdv.model.Estado
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo visto vocês setou de alguma forma para o jCombo aceitar somente "Estado".....
entao sua String nao pode ser "castada"(nen sei se essa palavra existe, mas agora passou a existir) para "Estado"..
Quando manipulo valores com jCombo eu simplismente deixo ela ao natural como veio ao mundo e adiciono String's nela e não Classes... depois para recuperar o item selecionado eu faço um for de comparação e capturo o mesmo...

Ou entao crie um estado com esse nome e tente adicionar como primeira opçao....